# Install node.js module for global use in command prompt

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have node.js module, made with type-script.
After installing type-script module globally:

```
npm install -g ts-node
```

I have made a module called **e2e**, which gets command prompt arguements.
After that I can call

```
ts-node e2e
```

But then, I still need to call this module e2e, via

```
e2e -a -b -c
```

where -a, -b, -c are command prompth params.

I tried to execute bat file like:

```
ts-node e2e -a -b -c
```

but it calls ts-node with this 4 parameters (e2e, -a, -b, -c).

How this problem could be solved? I finaly need to call e2e with params.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a shebang line as the first line of your script.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Then you will have it to be installed globally with:

```
npm install -g your-module
```

and for that you need to include the `bin` portion of package.json.
See the docs:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Or you can just copy it manually to some directory that you have in your PATH, like `/usr/bin/local/bin` etc. but it needs the shebang line and it has to be executable:

```
chmod a+x your-file-name
```

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)

### Example

For example on how to do it see my project on GitHub and npm that does exactly that:

#### Shebang line

See the shebang line in the script:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/ws-vs-si.js#L1

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env node
> ```

#### The package.json

See the `"bin"` portion in `package.json`:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/package.json#L9-L11

> ```
> "bin": {
>   "websocket-vs-socket.io": "ws-vs-si.js"
> },
> ```

As you can see, you can even install it under a different name than the original file was named.

#### Usage

And see the the instruction on how to install it and use it:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io#quick-start

> Install:
>
> ```
> npm i -g websocket-vs-socket.io
> ```
>
> Run the server:
>
> ```
> websocket-vs-socket.io
> ```

This is a pretty simple project that you can see at:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io

and:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-vs-socket.io

Comment: looks like I've described my problem wrong. I need to use my_module like "my_module -a -b -c", not "node my_module -a -b -c".

Comment: @Kamiky Yes. When you make a node script with the correct shebang line and put it in a directory that is in your PATH as I described in my answer it will work as `your_module` with no need to put `node` before that.

Comment: @Kamiky See my updated answer. I added links to my own project that demonstrates exactly what you want to do.